# IntelliSense source code not working in Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete, content-assist

I have problem while developing after update Xcode to version 10.

[image]

Comment: I always write the `init` word to let the completion helps, else it never appears. I remove the optional `init` word afterwards.

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your reply! But it seem not work in my machine. I tried but it always suggest something like image i uploaded above.

Comment: is it because UIKit isn't imported so it doesn't know what to suggest? also I always just use control space, or cmd space I forget which one, and the auto complete pops up

Comment: @TrầnTiếnĐạt In most of case it will happened when autocomplete is broken try to remove derived data and restart Xcode 